# How can i do this in Next Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In the NextJs application I want to add a route */cabinet* with navigation, despite the fact that the application itself already has a navigation bar defined in _app.js, is it possible to add an analog of _app.js for */cabinet* and */cabinet/something*. That is, add navigation for a separate directory with routes.

```
- pages
-- api
-- app.js
-- index.js
-- cabinet
--- settings.js
--- panel.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs don't mention any possibility of having multiple `_app.js` files, and I didn't see any allowance for it in a quick glance through the Next.js source either. So, you can either:

1. Refactor the nav bar into its own component and only import it where you need it, rather than leaving it in `_app.js`. (This is probably advisable.)
2. Or, modify `_app.js` to only render the regular navbar for urls outside the `cabinet` directory. You'll need to add the `router` prop to the component's parameter list, which is [always there](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/pages/_app.tsx) but not shown in the docs page for `_app.js`:

   ```
   function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, router }) {
     const isCabinet = router.pathname.includes("/cabinet/");
     return <>{ isCabinet ? <CabinetNav /> : <Nav /> }
       <Component {...pageProps} />
     </>;
   }
   ```